# Saving a file from Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am building a `Browser Action` type extension for chrome. The end result is that a user clicks the extension button, and starts to download a file from a known domain.

I have seen some similar answers but they all tell you how to generate the file (as I understand), whereas I have the file ready on the server.

I tried adding an A (link) element in the popup html, and having the user right click and "save as", but this option is not available in the extension popup. I have tried navigating the extension popup to the file's URL (location.href), but it shows a page not found error.

How can I just let the user download the file? Preferably when clicking the extension button but a second click inside the extension's html is acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in this recent thread: [CHROME ext/app - single click for image download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124336/chrome-ext-app-single-click-for-image-download)

Just using the download manager api (I always thought it was just to access the downloads list).